# Mouse events over groundoverlay in Google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to convert a GM v2 script i wrote years ago into v3.

I'm facing a problem with mouse events when over a groundoverlay (a weather radar map). I understand that v3 does not have this implemented in contrary to v2.

The events are working properly, as long as the mouse is not over the overlay.

How can i solve this ?

I must admit that my javascript knowledge has only been acquired in writing this script some years ago and that i didn't touch JS since...

Here my test page : http://www.egloff.eu/rsmaptest/rsmap.php

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In V3 mouse-events will fire on a GroundOverlay, when you click on a GroundOverlay the click will not fire on the underlying map.

All you have to do is to disable the mouse-events for the GroundOverlay by setting the `clickable`-option to `false`, e.g. :

```
radarMap = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(url,boundaries,{clickable:false});
```

Comment: Thanks a million !! That worked PERFECTLY.. I was starting to get crazy !! Now, i have to find out why my script is not working with IE ?

Comment: remove the trailing commas in line 280 & 307 of rsmap_v41.js

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the track, i found several other little problems. Now it works same in IE as FF. Now fighting with markers... i still have a icon definition problem. Markers appears ok with standard icons but not with custom one... Vielen Dank !